# "where in " clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq

below is my sql query

```
select * 
from test1View 
where test1ID in (select distinct(test2ID) from test2Result)
```

I want this query in Linq please

Comment: And I want people to be polite when they are asking for help. Shame neither of us can get what they want.

Comment: hoping this will 'throw-up' some nice answers :)

Comment: @Oded: I totally agree with your comment (+1 from me). Still, not everybody is a native speaker and yet we all try to do our software development job as good as we can ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below to achieve [where in](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/) functionality in linq

```
   DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        List<int> lstGroups = db.APP3_FRM2GRPs.Where(x => x.FGR_FRM_PKEY == Convert.ToInt32(ddlForms.SelectedValue)).Select(b => b.FGR_GRP_PKEY).ToList<int>();
        var qry = from item in db.APP3_GROUPs
                  where lstGroups.Contains(item.GRP_PKEY)
                  select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<int> subQuery = db.Test2Result
  .Select(tr => tr.Test2Id)
  .Distinct();

IQueryable<Test1View> query = db.Test1View
  .Where(tv => subQuery.Contains(tv.Test1ID);
```